# Montecarlo Pi Estimation code returning zero

Tags: python, montecarlo, pi

Having trouble getting this code to work. Only ever prints 0.0. I'm a complete beginner to python and I'm aware that I've probably made a very simple mistake, and that my code is poorly written.

```
import math
import random as ran
import numpy as np

nodarts=1000
nhits = 0




def isInTheCircle(nhits,nodarts):
    for i in range(nodarts):
          x = ran.uniform(-1,1) 
          y = ran.uniform(-1,1)
    if np.sqrt(x*x + y*y) >= 1:
        nhits += 1

isInTheCircle(nhits,nodarts)
pi = (4.0*nhits)/(nodarts)
print(pi)
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of nhits never changes from zero.

You have a function defined (isInTheCircle) and you call this function, but it does not return anything.  You need to rewrite it to return nhits and assign this value to a variable (presumably also called nhits).

```
def isInTheCircle(nhits,nodarts):
    for i in range(nodarts):
          x = ran.uniform(-1,1) 
          y = ran.uniform(-1,1)
        if np.sqrt(x*x + y*y) <= 1:
            nhits += 1

    return nhits


nhits = isInTheCircle(nhits,nodarts)
pi = (4.0*nhits)/(nodarts)
print(pi)
```

What may be confusing you is the "scope" of the variable nhits.  Basically, just because you have a variable named nhits inside and outside the function does NOT make them the same variable.  The variable inside the function changes, but the variable outside the function does not necessarily change (it does sometimes depending on type....but that's another story).  Read up on "variable scope in python" to better understand this.

Comment: Also the `if` needs to be inside the `for` loop and for checking, if the dart is inside the circle, it needs to be `<=`

Comment: @user8408080 Good points.  I was looking at the bigger picture, but those details are critical.  Thanks for pointing this out.  Updated to include your comments.

Comment: Appreciate the help, I've made the suggested the adjustments and the code is working perfectly, thank you!